# Inserting code method should be changed

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I realize this suggestion would affect only the Stack Exchange sites that use code as part of their questions. However, since my suggestion would involve a re-code, if it's accepted, I thought it best to post it here. It's simple:

Currently when we post code we have to use four spaces to make a code block; this is true for each line of code. Instead of this method, how about we accept an HTML-like markup for code, like `<code>` to begin code and `</code>` to end it.

It's quicker for the typist. Secondly, it ensures that someone's code doesn't fail to appear because they accidentally only indented three spaces, not four. Thirdly, with the beginning and end tags, `<code>` and `</code>`, it makes the process a breeze.

So, what's the consensus on this?

Comment: Try using \`\`\` before and after your code without indenting it at all. The three ticks should be on lines by themselves.

Comment: `tab` instead of four spaces also works. Also `<code>...</code>` will give inline code

Comment: [But TABs are to be banned](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBWAP_8zxaM&t=8m49s)

Answer (score 8):

Indenting by four spaces isn't the only way to format code. For code blocks, you can also either add ```` ``` ```` to the beginning and end of the code block or enclose it in the `<pre> </pre>` tags. has the same effect as indenting by for spaces.

Four-space indentation:

```
Hello
World
!
```

Triple quote syntax:

```
Hello
World
!
```

`<pre> </pre>` syntax:

```
Hello
World
!
```

Also remember that there's a builtin way to format code blocks without having to manually indent every line of code. When you're writing or editing a post, just highlight the section of code and click the curly braces on the editing bar.

[image]

Comment: Highlighting the text and pressing Ctrl+K will also format as code.

Comment: Four-space indentation and triple-quote syntax will be rendered as <pre><code>. Note that using <pre> without <code> won't add the syntax highlighting.